# How to aggregate data in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a data set `test1.txt`. It contain data like below

```
2::1::3
1::1::2
1::2::2
2::1::5
2::1::4
3::1::2
3::1::1
3::2::2
```

I have created data-frame using the below code.

```
case class Test(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Float)
def pRating(str: String): Rating = {
val fields = str.split("::")
assert(fields.size == 3)
Test(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toFloat)
}

val ratings = spark.read.textFile("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test1.txt").map(pRating).toDF()
2,1,3
1,1,2
1,2,2
2,1,5
2,1,4
3,1,2
3,1,1
3,2,2
```

But I want to print output like below I.e. removing duplicate combinations and instead of `field(2) value sum of values1,1, 2.0`.

```
1,1,2.0
1,2,2.0
2,1,12.0
3,1,3.0
3,2,2.0
```

Please help me on this, how can achieve this.

Comment: dataframe.groupBy("column1","column2").sum("column3") should works

Comment: Thanks Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ratings.groupBy("userId","movieId").sum(rating)
```

Comment: This code does not satisfy the requirement to remove duplicate rows. You need `distinct` before `groupBy`.

Answer (score 4):

To drop duplicates, use `df.distinct`. To aggregate you first `groupBy` and then `agg`. Putting this all together:

```scala
case class Rating(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Float)

def pRating(str: String): Rating = {
  val fields = str.split("::")
  assert(fields.size == 3)
  Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toFloat)
}

val ratings = spark.read.textFile("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test1.txt").map(pRating)
val totals = ratings.distinct
  .groupBy('userId, 'movieId)
  .agg(sum('rating).as("rating"))
  .as[Rating]
```

I am not sure you'd want the final result as `Dataset[Rating]` and whether the `distinct` and `sum` logic is exactly as you'd want it as the example in the question is not very clear but, hopefully, this will give you what you need.